# Parse-server before delete on Session or Logout

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to write a hook for when a user logs out.

I tried `Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete('Session', ...)`

That doesn't work.  I tried [`BeforeDeleteRequest`](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Cloud.BeforeDeleteRequest.html) on `Session` and that won't even build, apparently BeforeDeleteRequest is not a function.

Is there anyway to grab the user object upon logout?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following in the source code of Parse.Cloud:

```
var restrictedClassNames = ['_Session'];
if (restrictedClassNames.indexOf(className) != -1) {
    throw 'Triggers are not supported for ' + className + ' class.';
}
```

It looks like hooks on Session are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing PR for an `afterLogout` trigger on the `_Session` class, so expect this feature to be added soon. This should address the issue you describe.

https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/pull/6217